# how to reduce the amount of memory my android app uses

Tags: java, android, debugging

recently i have started working on this app what it does is show a little joystick on the screen and when you press the arrow to android icon moves to where its pressed

this works fine in the emulator but as soon as i try it on my phone it crashes instantly
im guessing my program is using to memory so how can i limit this?
thanks

```
package net.jegard.software.zombie.main;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

    public class zombView extends SurfaceView{
        private Bitmap bmp, grass, joystick;
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        boolean forward, left, down, right;
        public zombView(Context context) {
              super(context);
              holder = getHolder();
              holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                     @Override
                     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {


                         t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                             public void run(){
                            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                            onDraw(c);
                            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                            onTouchEvent(null);
                         }
                     },200,100);
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                   int width, int height) {
                     }
              });
              bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
              grass = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grassland);
              joystick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.joystic);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
              canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
              canvas.drawBitmap(grass, getWidth() - getWidth(), getHeight() - getHeight(), null);
              canvas.drawBitmap(joystick, getWidth() - getWidth(),joystick.getHeight(), null);
              canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
              if(right){
                    x = x + 10;
              }
              if(forward){
                y = y - 10;
              }if(left){
                x = x - 10;
              }if(down){
                y = y + 10;
              }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float tx = event.getX();
                float ty = event.getY();
                if(tx > (joystick.getWidth()/3)*2 && tx < (joystick.getWidth()/3)*3 && ty > (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3) && ty < (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3)*2){
                        touch_right(tx, ty);
                        invalidate();
                }if(tx > (joystick.getWidth()/3) && tx < (joystick.getWidth()/3)*2 && ty > (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) && ty < (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3)){
                        touch_forward(tx, ty);
                        invalidate();
                }if(tx > (joystick.getWidth() - joystick.getWidth()) && tx < (joystick.getWidth()/3) && ty > (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3) && ty < (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3)*2){
                    touch_left(tx, ty);
                    invalidate();
                }if(tx > (joystick.getWidth()/3) && tx < (joystick.getWidth()/3)*2 && ty > ((getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight()/3)*2) && ty < (getHeight() - joystick.getHeight()) + (joystick.getHeight())){
                    touch_down(tx, ty);
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   
                touch_move();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
             return true;
        }

        private void touch_right(float x2, float y2) {
            right = true;

        }
        private void touch_left(float x2, float y2) {
            left = true;

        }
        private void touch_down(float x2, float y2) {
            down = true;

        }
        private void touch_forward(float x2, float y2) {
            forward = true;

        }
        private void touch_move() {
            touch_up();

        }

        private void touch_up() {
            forward = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;


        }
    }
```

Comment: As always, anytime you have a crash in Android that you're asking a question about, post the stack trace from LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a memory issue at all, try connecting your phone in debug mode and check the logs. It will give you the clear picture of the real problem.

Comment: In your phone, go to "Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging" enable it, and in eclipse go to DDMS View and select your phone.